# Write a PID file manually from Bash script

Tags: bash

How could I write a Bash-script that runs a long running program and stores the programs process id in a separate file?

I want something like

```
#!/bin/bash
exec long_running_tool
echo `ps af |grep "long_running_tool" |awk '$5 == "long_running_tool" {print $1}'` > pid_file
```

However doing exactly this would execute the `ps` after *tool* has finished.

Is there a way to get the process id of the process created?

Comment: Your sample code won't work because exec doesn't fork, so the shell process is replaced by the `long_running_tool` process. Consequently, exec never returns and the following line is never reached. See `help exec`, `execve(2)`.

Comment: @e-t172 thank you for pointing out. I delete 'exec' then.

Comment: Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can easily run the process in the background with "&", then get the PID of the background process using "$!"

```
#!/bin/bash
long_running_tool &
echo $! > pid_file
```

Then, optionally, wait $! if you want the shell to block until the process completes execution.

Comment: UPDATE: when I use the fg I get 'fg: 21: job (null) not created under job control' and the script does not block. Sorry.

Comment: "wait $!" should have a similar effect to fg that I can confirm does in fact, work in a script. I should probably have checked that before posting. >.> my bad.

Answer (score 16):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $$ > fooapp.pid
exec fooapp
```

As mentioned earlier, `exec` *replaces* `bash` with the specified program, *retaining* the PID.

Comment: interesting. this is useful esp. putting it in a sub-shell `( ... )`. I wonder what's the pros/cons compared to backgrounding and wait.