# Write PID To File On Bash Execution

Tags: bash, cron, bash-scripting

I'm executing a bash script via cron. I want to write the process id (PID) of the script to a `/tmp/` file for reference, in case I need to kill it later on (this script can take 6 - 10 hours to complete).

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo ${PID} > /tmp/backup_pid
...
rest of the script
```

Each time the script executes `tar` or `rsync`, they are launched as independant processes, hence why I'd like this PID feature.

This answer (https://superuser.com/a/238533/314696) suggests using `eval`, but I've been taught that `eval` is ev**i**l. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell variable `$$` contains the PID of the current running script. You could use it like this:

```
echo $$ >/tmp/backup_pid
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get PID:

```
    pgrep Process                ###Write process name instead of "Process"###
```

If you want to get PID and kill process from GNOME Terminal:

```
    pid=$(pgrep Process) && kill -9 $pid
```

If you want to end a task with shell scripting:

```
    pdi=$pgrep Process)
    kill -9 $pid
```

Or write PID to a file:

```
    pgrep Process > FileName.Format
```